# How to drag a group in Konva JS only from an inner shape and not from other areas of the group?

Tags: konvajs

I want to drag the entire group from the center red square, (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cdw3ya7/19/))

but restrict dragging from the outer rectangle, while maintaining the inner rectangle's position inside the group.
Possibly when mouse is down I want the crosshair cursor to be dead in the center of the inner red rectangle.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
   container: 'container',
   width: window.innerWidth,
   height: window.innerHeight
});
let layer = new Konva.Layer();
let group = new Konva.Group({
  draggable: true,
  height:50,
  width: 50
});

const containerRect = new Konva.Rect({
    width:50,
  height: 50,
  fill: 'yellow'
});

const rect = new Konva.Rect({
    x: 15,
  y: 15,
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  fill: 'red'
});
stage.add(layer);
group.add(containerRect);
group.add(rect);
layer.add(group);
layer.draw();
```

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are asking. Willing to get involved if you can provide more explanation please. Maybe modify your fiddle by making the two rects bigger and adding shapes / groups and explaining more.

Comment: When you make a group draggable, then you can click the mouse anywhere inside the group and drag it. I want to be able to drag the entire group **only** from the red rectangle within. Additionally, I asked another question, which was, is it possible during mouse down to shift the pointer to the center of the shape to avoid dragging it from the side.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making the red rectangle `draggable`. Once you start a drag, you can stop it and start dragging of the group:

```
rect.on('dragstart', () => {
  // stop rect dragging
  rect.stopDrag();

  // move group to the center
  const size = group.getClientRect();
  const pos = stage.getPointerPosition();

  group.setAttrs({
     x: pos.x - size.width / 2,
     y: pos.y - size.height / 2,
  });
  group.startDrag();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0cdw3ya7/21/